# ¿Cómo rescatar los datos de un array enviado por Ajax en PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, array

Tengo un array y un ajax como el siguiente:

```
data = [[15,"comentario 1","descripcion 1"][15,"comentario 2","descripcion 2"]];

$('#loader-icon').show();
$('#targetLayer').hide();
    $.ajax({
        url: "post/utileria_guardar_imagenTotal.php",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(respuesta){
```

y bueno de allí en adelante finalizo la `function`, y del lado de utileria_guardar_imagenTotal.php tengo:

```
    <?php 

include('../../bd/utileria_BD.php');
$respuesta=guardar_imagenTotal($_POST);
echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

y adicionalmente  tengo en esa dirección:

```
function guardar_imagenTotal($datos){
    include("conexion.php");

    $idInforme = $link->insert_id;

    for ($i=1; $i < count($datos); $i++) { 

        $link->query("INSERT INTO archivos (
            idinforme,
            nombreArchivo,
            descripcionArchivo,
            extensionArchivo
        ) VALUES (
          '".utf8_decode($idInforme)."',

        //Valores que necesito ingresar
          '".utf8_decode($datos[$i][0])."',
          '".utf8_decode($datos[$i][1])."',
          '".utf8_decode($datos[$i][2])."'
    )");

}   

$respuesta=1;
$link->close();
return $respuesta;
```

Por lo que la pregunta realmente sería: Si envié ese array por ajax, ¿Cómo rescataría los datos pertenecientes de dicho array del otro lado?

Comment: Haz un `print_r($_POST)` quizas esto te ayude a entender lo que recibes y como utilizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comprender mejor tu pregunta y ya que no utilizo el método $.ajax() utilice un boton que me ejecuta la función, Elimina el dataType para que puedas visualizar lo que te manda como respuesta, verás que es un array, para acceder tendrías que hacer a un valor sería $data[0][1];

```js
data = [[15,"comentario 1","descripcion 1"],[15,"comentario 2","descripcion 2"]];
$('#ajax').click(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: "prueba.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {'data':JSON.stringify(data)},//Tienes que utilizar el método JSON.stringify(data)
    //dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function(respuesta){
      console.log(respuesta);
      
    }
});

 });
```

```html
<button id="ajax">click</button>
```

Y en el backend lo recibes así.

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: No me funciona :/, una pregunta tendrías tiempo para conectarte y ayudarme, de verdad no conozco a nadie que sepa PHP para que me explique.

Comment: De hecho estyo haciendo el ejemplo en mi localHost, y tienes un error en tu data, no esta separado el arreglo debería estar así `data = [[15,"comentario 1","descripcion 1"],[15,"comentario 2","descripcion 2"]];` y conectarme a dónde?

Comment: Tranquilo el arreglo lo hice a mano XD por eso ese error, el codigo en si no lo tiene, y pues por apper.in asi comparto pantalla

Comment: Edito mi respuesta.

Comment: No me funciona del todo, pero casi siempre me ayudas así que +

Comment: :// no me deja tranquilo, mira esto es lo que pasas por el PHP `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(15)
    [1]=>
    string(12) "comentario 1"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "descripcion 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(15)
    [1]=>
    string(12) "comentario 2"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "descripcion 2"
  }
}`, de ahí sólo tienes que acceder por el índice, así $data[0][0] y esto te devuelve **15**.

Comment: Lo siento @vickMuñoz es que no entiendo como lo haces, asi que tranquilo, anteriormente ya me has ayudado bastante, asi que seguire tratando :D